# Rspec (run when flag is set)

Tags: rspec, rspec-rails, rspec3

How do I run an rspec test only when a flag is set?

I am using Stripe-Ruby-Mock and they use a `live` flag. However, I do not want the test to run when `-t live` is not set.

`bundle exec rspec -t live spec`

```
it "should run rspec test, only when live is true", live: true do
  expect('value').to eq('value')
end
```

Currently, my test runs when `-t live` is set AND when it's not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Configure RSpec to filter out that tag by default in your `spec_helper.rb` using [`#filter_run_excluding`](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/rspec/rspec-core/RSpec%2FCore%2FConfiguration:filter_run_excluding):

```rb
config.filter_run_excluding live: true
```

That way they will only run when you specify the tag on the command line.

Answer (score 1):

You can set an environment variable:

> LIVE=true bundle exec rspec spec

Then in your code you can use ENV['LIVE'] as `if(conditional filter)`.
for details check [conditional filters](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-8/docs/filtering/conditional-filters)